# How to pass parameters to routes in flutter auto_route

Tags: flutter

How can I pass values from main to the initial route of the app? I want to get the data from a sqflite database. I would prefer to make the initialization inside main function rather than the initial route and I am trying to figure out how to set the routes

main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await configureLocalTimeZone();
  getIt.registerLazySingleton<UserRepositories>(() => UserRepositories());
  getIt.registerSingleton<AppRouter>(AppRouter());
  initializeNotifications();
  DatabaseService databaseService = DatabaseService.instance;
  final alarms = await databaseService.getAlarms();
  AppRouter router = AppRouter();
  runApp(MyApp(appRouter: router));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final AppRouter appRouter;
  MyApp({Key? key, required this.appRouter}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
      BlocProvider<UserBloc>(
        create: (_) => UserBloc()..add(FetchUser()), // Add FetchUser event here
      ),
      BlocProvider<LoginBloc>(
        create: (_) => LoginBloc(userRepository: getIt<UserRepositories>()), // Add FetchUser event here
      ),
    ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          routerConfig: appRouter.config(),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

AppRouter.dart

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

import 'app_router.gr.dart';

@AutoRouterConfig(replaceInRouteName: 'Screen,Route')
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {


  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    AutoRoute(page: MainRoute.page, initial: true), // I WANT TO PASS ALARMS AND SERVICE TO MAIN SCREEN
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According the auto_route's official documentation, the arguments are automatically detected and included in the generated routes.

All you need to do is include the argument in the page's constructor:

```dart
@RoutePage()      
class BookDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {                    
 const BookDetailsPage({required this.book});                    
                    
  final Book book;                 
  ...
```

Then you can pass arguments to the page using the generated constructor:

```dart
router.push(BookDetailsRoute(book: book));
```

You can even have functions as route arguments:

```dart
@RoutePage()                    
class BookDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {                    
 const BookDetailsRoute({this.book, required this.onRateBook});                    
                    
  final Book book;                    
  final void Function(int) onRateBook;                    
  ...
```

```dart
context.pushRoute(                    
      BookDetailsRoute(                    
          book: book,                    
          onRateBook: (rating) {                    
           // handle result                    
          }),                    
    );
```

If you also want your parameter to be visible in the path, you can use `@PathParam` or `@QueryParam` annotations:

```dart
class BookDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {                    
  const BookDetailsPage({@PathParam('id') this.bookId});                
                  
  final int bookId;                    
  ...
```

But make sure to include the path param in the route's declaration:

```dart
AutoRoute(        
   path: '/product/:id',        
   page: ProductRoute.page,        
   children: [        
      AutoRoute(path: 'review',page: ProductReviewRoute.page),        
  ],      
),
```

Navigating to `/product/1` will take you to `ProductPage` with `productId` equal to `1`.

Passing arguments: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#passing-arguments

Path Parameters: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#path-parameters-dynamic-segments

Query Parameters: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Update the `MainRoute.page` to accept the required data, such as `alarms` and `databaseService`.

```dart
class MainRoutePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Alarm> alarms;
  final DatabaseService databaseService;

  MainRoutePage({
    Key? key, 
    required this.alarms, 
    required this.databaseService
  }) : super(key: key);
  
  ...
}
```

Modify your `AppRouter` to accept these values and pass them to the `MainRoute.page`.

```dart
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {
  final List<Alarm> alarms;
  final DatabaseService databaseService;

  AppRouter({
    required this.alarms,
    required this.databaseService,
  });

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    AutoRoute(
      page: MainRoute.page, 
      initial: true, 
      args: [alarms, databaseService]
    ),
  ];
}
```

In your `main` function, pass the `alarms` and `databaseService` to the `AppRouter` when you're instantiating it.

```dart
AppRouter router = AppRouter(alarms: alarms, databaseService: databaseService);
```

Now, when the `MainRoute.page` is created, it will receive both the `alarms` and `databaseService` as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

AutoRoute automatically detects and handles your page arguments for you, the generated route object will deliver all the arguments your page needs including path/query params.

e.g. The following page widget will take an argument of type Book.

```
@RoutePage()      
class BookDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {                    
 const BookDetailsPage({required this.book});                    
                    
  final Book book;                 
  ...
```

Note: Default values are respected. Required fields are also respected and handled properly.

The generated BookDetailsRoute will deliver the same arguments to its corresponding page.

```
router.push(BookDetailsRoute(book: book));
```